# PostgreSQL Triggering INSERT INTO other table

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am trying to learn triggers in PGSQL 13. It seems easy but still I don't get the right result. I have two tables `hist.T1` and `public.T2` in two different schemas.

T1 contains three columns `stream_id`, `timestamp` and `o_value` with numbers from 11 to 20. Every 5 second I receive new record with new value. I want to get In T2 records with values below 15.
T2 contains columns `s_id`, `TrigTime`, `n_value`.

I created Function and trigger as below

**FUNCTION**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TestFunct()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
  DECLARE

BEGIN

IF NEW.o_value < 15 AND NEW.stream_id = 1 THEN 
  INSERT INTO public.T2(s_id, TrigTime, n_value) 
  VALUES(NEW.stream_id, NEW.timestamp , NEW.o_value);
END IF;
RETURN NEW;

END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**TRIGGER**

```
CREATE  TRIGGER TestTrig
AFTER INSERT ON hist.T1
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.TestFunct();
```

The result was very unexpected for me. In T1 I do not receive records with values < 15 at all. It seems like it is deleting these rows because i see 10 second interval between new rows. In T2 I do not receive new rows at all.

**Testing of trigger**

For testing I am using OPC Server Simulator that send to system data every single minute. Database has set a read time for 5 second so every single 5 second I receive data from OPC to database. I receive values from 11 to 20.
By changing the the condition in trigger function I can test how the trigger works.

For example when I am changing condition `NEW.o_value < 15` to `< 11` then I can see the trigger is never activated which is exepcted result.
How do I recognize that trigger is activated? As I wrote previously when trigger is activated database starts to miss data in `T1`. Instead getting data regularly every 5 second I get them every 10 seconds and only higher then in condition which means that records that are fine with conditions are just not appearing on source table `T1`.

After changing this to `< 11` I get all records every 5 seconds as function is not triggered.

No matter what I am doing I never get values in destination table `public.T2`

**Troubleshooting**

I tried several things but none of them worked.

- I tried changing interval for source database for 15 seconds instead
  of 5. (I hope it is clear that in this case I started to get data in
  source table every 30 seconds if function is triggered)
- I tried changing `EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.TestFunct()` for `EXECUTE FUNCTION public.TestFunct()`
- I tried using `INSERT INTO public.T2(s_id, TrigTime, n_value) VALUES(NEW.stream_id, NEW.timestamp , NEW.o_value)` without using
  trigger, just by querying this in database with specific values and
  insert was succesfull
- I tried to change the whole `INSERT INTO` in trigger function so it
  would just place some static data in `public.T2`
- I tried to change `INSERT INTO` in trigger function so I would just
  place 1 new value in whole record.
- I tried to change `INSERT INTO` in trigger function to place new value
  in every single column in whole record.
- I tried to move trigger function between schemas.

Result was always the same. Missing data in source table and now new data in destination table.

Comment: How did you test?

Comment: 1) To me this seems backwards, I am assuming `hist` means history and that this is where the data would be headed after inserts in `public.T2`. 2) Your function code is testing for `NEW.o_value < 15 AND NEW.stream_id = 1`. Are you sure you are not seeing the results of just pulling from stream 1?

Comment: 1) No, it is as I mentioned in question. Hist is a historian schema database that recieves data from OPC Server. I got there database which receives record every 5 second and some of these records with specified conditions I wanted to store in another table (public.T2).
2) This one is actually bit tricky. stream_id contain information about which tag from OPC Server I am checking and in fact right now I am checking only one tag so every single record contains there an integer value "1". I tried before without this condition but the result was the same.

Comment: I am testing this with OPC Simulator which gives me every second value from 11 to 20. That means that every 10 seconds I got two records where one of them is usually <15. Yes, I know it gives me o only 4 values below vs 6 values higher but I placed this condition <15 just for an example. I am using pgAdmin to see retrieved data and I used pgadmin to create trigger and function.

Comment: Additionally about testing. When I am switching condition in trigger to <11 for example than I can see on 'hist.T1' that I am receiving values ever 5 seconds 13, 18, 13, 18, and so on. After editing this once again to <15 or <16 I am getting in hist.T1 only 18, 18, 18 every 10 seconds. Nothing appears in 'public.T2' and I have no idea why suddenly I don't receive all data in 'hist.T1'

Comment: it seems the insert to T2 is throwing an error (wrong datatype, missing required value etc), so the whole transaction is rolled backed (nothing seems inserted in T1 for these values). Try to run the insert to T2 by hand with the same values. Fix the insert statement, and most importantly fix your wrapper call so that you can detect when an error occurs!

Comment: Update you question with the further information, don't do that in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I checked logs for database

```
2023-05-24 15:25:30.206 CEST [4164] ERROR:  permission denied for table T2
2023-05-24 15:25:30.206 CEST [4164] LOG: statement: "INSERT INTO public.T2(s_id, TrigTime, n_value)
              VALUES(NEW.stream_id, NEW.timestamp , NEW.o_value)"
            PL/pgSQL trigger_function() function, line 5
2023-05-24 15:25:30.206 CEST [4164] LOG: statement:  INSERT INTO T1 (stream_id, timestamp, o_value ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
```

I was using superuser but I granted additionally permission for all users for this table. By all users I mean postgres superuser and OPCuser responsible for inserting new data in T1.
After that I received:

```
2023-05-24 15:44:05.272 CEST [4164] ERROR: permission denied for sequence T2_id_seq
2023-05-24 15:44:05.272 CEST [4164] LOG: statement: "INSERT INTO public.T2(s_id, TrigTime, n_value)
              VALUES(NEW.stream_id, NEW.timestamp , NEW.o_value)"
            PL/pgSQL trigger_function() function, line 5
2023-05-24 15:44:05.272 CEST [4164] LOG: statement:  INSERT INTO T1 (stream_id, timestamp, o_value ) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
```

Granting permissions for OPCuser on T2 table and T2_id_seq helped and solved the whole issue.